# How to import an Oracle DB .dmp file using DBeaver?

Tags: database, oracle, import, dbeaver

I'm currently trying to import an Oracle DB .dmp (dump) file into my Oracle DB using DBeaver but have trouble doing so.

The Oracle DB in question is running in a docker container. I successfully connected to this Oracle database with DBeaver, and can thus browse the database using DBeaver.
Currently however, the DB is empty. That's where the .dmp file comes in.

I want to import this .dmp file into my database, under a certain schema but I cannot seem to do this. The dump file looks something like this: 'export.dmp' and is around 16MB big.

I'd like to import the data from the .dmp file to be able to browse the data to get familiar with it, as similar data will be stored in our own database.

I looked online but was unable to get an answer that works for me.

I tried using DBeaver but I don't seem to have the option to import or restore a DB via a .dmp file. At best, DBeaver proposes to import data using a .CSV file. I also downloaded the Oracle tool SQLDeveloper, but I can't manage to connect to my database in the docker container.

Online there is also talk of an import / export tool that supposedly can create these .dmp files and import them, but I'm unsure how to get this tool and whether that is the way to do it.
If so, I still don't understand how I can get to browse the data in DBeaver.

**How can I import and browse the data from the .dmp file in my Oracle DB using DBeaver?**

Comment: `IMP` or `IMPDP` are tools for importing dumps. Copy the backup file into the database's docker container and then use the import tool inside the container (rather than trying to do it from outside the container).

Answer (score 2):

1. [How to find Oracle datapump dir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29077007/how-to-change-oracle-default-data-pump-directory-to-import-dumpfile)

   > presumably set to /u01/app/oracle/admin/<mydatabase>/dpdump on your system
2. [How to copy files from host to docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22907231/how-to-copy-files-from-host-to-docker-container)

   ```
   docker cp export.dmp container_id:/u01/app/oracle/admin/<mydatabase>/dpdump/export.dmp
   ```
3. [How do I get into a Docker container's shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30172605/how-do-i-get-into-a-docker-containers-shell)

   ```
   docker exec -it <mycontainer> bash
   ```
4. [How to import an Oracle database from dmp file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6463614/how-to-import-an-oracle-database-from-dmp-file-and-log-file)

   > If it was exported using expdp, then start the import with impdp:

   ```
   impdp <username>/<password> dumpfile=export.dmp full=y
   ```

   It will output the log file in the same default DATA_PUMP_DIR directory in the container.

Answer (score 0):

oracle has two utilities IMPORT and IMPDP to import dumps ,  with IMPORT you can't use database directories and you have to specify the location . The IMPDP on other hand require database directory .
having said that you can't import oracle export dumps using dbeaver , you have to use IMPORT or IMPDP utility from OS.